# How to use internationalization in chameleon with pyramid web framework?

Tags: python, internationalization, pyramid, chameleon

I have done the following:

1. Change `pyramid.default_locale_name = en` to `de` in development.ini
2. My `index.pt` looks like this:

   ```
   <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" xmlns:tal="http://xml.zope.org namespaces/tal" xmlns:i18n="http://xml.zope.org/namespaces/i18n"  i18n:domain="mvc">
   <a href="/user/login/form" i18n:translate="">Login Page</a><br />
   <a href="/user/register/form" i18n:translate="">Register Page</a><br />
   <a href="/ds/landing/view" i18n:translate="">Datasource landing page</a> <br />
   <p>${locale_name}</p>
   ```
3. I have made changes to the setup.py

   ```
   message_extractors = { '.': [
   ('**.py',   'lingua_python', None ),
   ('**.pt',   'lingua_xml', None ),
   ]}
   ```
4. When I run `python  setup.py extract_messages` and `python setup.py update_catalog` my `locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/mvc.po` gets all the strings. After translation it becomes

   ```
   # German translations for mvc.
   # Copyright (C) 2012 ORGANIZATION
   # This file is distributed under the same license as the mvc project.
   # FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, 2012.
   #
   msgid ""
   msgstr ""
   "Project-Id-Version: mvc 0.0\n"
   "Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: EMAIL@ADDRESS\n"
   "POT-Creation-Date: 2012-05-02 12:24+0530\n"
   "PO-Revision-Date: 2012-05-02 11:38+0530\n"
   "Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
   "Language-Team: de <LL@li.org>\n"
   "Plural-Forms: nplurals=2; plural=(n != 1)\n"
   "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
   "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\n"
   "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"
   "Generated-By: Babel 0.9.6\n"

   #: mvc/templates/index.pt:2
   msgid "Login Page"
   msgstr "sign in page"

   #: mvc/templates/index.pt:3
   #, fuzzy
   msgid "Register Page"
   msgstr "register in this Page"

   #: mvc/templates/index.pt:4
   msgid "Datasource landing page"
   msgstr "Landing Page of datasources"
   ```

   Ignore the English as I have not done any actual translation. I want to check if it works.
5. I did `python setup.py compie_catalog` and mvc.mo file is created
6. But when I load the page I am getting the same page without translations getting picked up. The locale seems to have set properly as I can see from the view

   ```
   @view_config(route_name='home',renderer='templates/index.pt')
   def index_view(request):
       from pyramid.i18n import negotiate_locale_name

       return {'locale_name' : negotiate_locale_name(request)}
   ```
7. I have even added `config.add_translation_dirs('mvc:locale')` to my **init**.py

What am I doing wrong? Or am I doing anything right at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you configure the translation domain for your translations?

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/1.3-branch/narr/i18n.html#translation-domains